# How to correctly Validate user entry in Django Generic Views

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-validation

In my Django app I am trying to validate a form field value entered by the user. I am trying to do the validation in Django generic `UpdateView` (as I will explain below). The extant field stores various statuses of a transaction document. The change in **status** happens at update (either by the user manually entering the status code OR based upon certain phase of transaction or the like - *not important here*).

The important thing is that on `save` the status of the document needs to change. As there are a number of statuses, each of them have been given a numerical value. Wherever the statuses are manually entered, the need is to check if the current **status** value is **less** than the entered value. If it is not, the user should get an **error message**.

My views.py looks like this:

```
class ProdDocView(UpdateView, ...):
    template_name = ...
    model = ProdLine
    form_class = ProdLineForm
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        tmp_status = ProdLine.objects.get(prod_doc_id=self.object.pk).prod_doc_status
        new_status_entered = form.cleaned_data['prod_doc_status']

        if tmp_status == new_status_entered:    # This is just to check error capture
            # raise ValidationError('Wrong status code entered!!')
            return super(ProdDocView, self).form_invalid(form)
        else:
            form.instance.approved_by = self.request.user.   # This is to save user field on successful save
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Now what is happening is, the error trapping happens - i.e. if the the previous status matches the status entered, saving fails. **But no error message is displayed**. If the statuses are **unequal**, the document successfully saves.

As you can see, the `raise ValidationError('Wrong status code entered!!')` code line has been commented out, because otherwise the form fails and the error is displayed in the browser (with the error message).

### My question is:

**How can I display the error to the front end user?**

Comment: You should add the validation in `clean` method of the form like in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).
Also in the template, make sure you have added the code for showing validation errors.

Comment: How do I get the value of the **status** of the object being _edited_ so as to compare with the new value entered?

Comment: Solved it. I just needed to add `form.add_error('prod_doc_status', 'Wrong status code entered!!')`. The error message shows up against the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the question, I am reproducing my comment above:

I just needed to add the following:

`form.add_error('prod_doc_status', 'Wrong status code entered!!')`

With this, the error message shows up against the field.